# Send hex value via command arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Python to call a JS file via Node.

If I used a built in variable my code works well, but via command arguments it's not.

```js
console.log(
  "Correct -->",
  "\x7b\x6e\xd6\x05\xca\x8a\x52\xfb\x01\xf4\x1e\xa1\x04\x10\x7f\xdc"
);
console.log("Invalid -->", process.argv[2]);
```

Now using `node script.js "\x7b\x6e\xd6\x05\xca\x8a\x52\xfb\x01\xf4\x1e\xa1\x04\x10\x7f\xdc"`

I got the below output:

```
Correct --> {nÖ♣ÊRû☺ô▲¡♦►⌂Ü
Invalid --> \x7b\x6e\xd6\x05\xca\x8a\x52\xfb\x01\xf4\x1e\xa1\x04\x10\x7f\xdc
```

How to get `console.log(process.argv[2])` works same as the built in one?

Comment: i think what's going on is the shell doesn't escape any of the hex values... it's literally passing on text. you're gonna have to parse it with like `const hexValues = hexString.replace(/\\x/g, '').match(/.{1,2}/g);`
`// Convert the array of hexadecimal values to a buffer`
`const buffer = Buffer.from(hexValues.map(hex => parseInt(hex, 16)));`
or use base64

Comment: is that what you meant ? https://bpa.st/7V6Q as am getting buffer output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will decode the argument string:

```js
const expected = "\x7b\x6e\xd6\x05\xca\x8a\x52\xfb\x01\xf4\x1e\xa1\x04\x10\x7f\xdc";

const decodeHex = (hex) =>
  hex
    .split(/(?=\\x)/g)
    .map((v) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v.replace(/^\\x/g, ""), 16)))
    .join("");

const decoded = decodeHex(process.argv[2]);

console.log("Expected -->", expected);
console.log("Decoded  -->", decoded);
console.log("Equal    -->", decoded === expected); // true
```

When calling the script via:

```bash
node script.js "\x7b\x6e\xd6\x05\xca\x8a\x52\xfb\x01\xf4\x1e\xa1\x04\x10\x7f\xdc"
```

Output:

```
Expected --> {nÖ♣ÊRû☺ô▲¡♦►⌂Ü
Decoded  --> {nÖ♣ÊRû☺ô▲¡♦►⌂Ü
Equal    --> true
```

Alternatively, you could define `decodeHex` as:

```js
import { Buffer } from "node:buffer";

const decodeHex = (hex) =>
  String.fromCharCode(
    ...Buffer.from(
      hex.match(/(?<=\\x)[a-f\d]{1,2}/g).map((v) => parseInt(v, 16))
    )
  );
```